How to Print full slip when applying ScrollViewer
I have this code in where I am printing slip for my wpf application.
Here the printing is working fine if I just click on print button and is printing full slip from top to bottom. The issue occurs when I scroll and only some portion of page is visible and some is not like the picture blow:

when I print it prints only the visible part from above

this is the code i have that i am using for printing.
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Main content takes most of the space -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <!-- Footer section is auto-sized -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PrintArea" Margin="10">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Header Row -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <!-- Repeat ColumnDefinitions here for consistent width -->
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- Sr. -->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        <!-- Qty -->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        <!-- Price -->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                        <!-- Total -->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Sr." FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Qty" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Price" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Total" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>

                <!-- DetailSectionItems -->
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DetailSectionItemsSection" ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveInvoice.InvoiceItems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <!-- Display Name and Code above item details -->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                  TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="300"/>

                                <!-- Item details row -->
                                <Grid Margin="0,2,0,2">
                                    <!-- Repeat ColumnDefinitions here as well -->
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <!-- Sr. -->
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                        <!-- Qty -->
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                        <!-- Price -->
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                                        <!-- Total -->
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <!-- Serial Number using AlternationIndex -->
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="40"
                                      Text="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}, 
                                      Converter={StaticResource IndexToSrNoConverter}}"/>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Quantity}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="40"/>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding DataContext.ActiveInvoice.ViewableCurrency, 
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SalePrice}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding DataContext.ActiveInvoice.ViewableCurrency, 
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding InvoiceItemNetTotal}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>

                                <!-- Divider Line -->
                                <Line X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>


            <Separator Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>

This is code For
    public partial class PosDefaultWindow : Window
    {
        //private InvoiceViewModel _invoiceViewModel;
        private SalesTerminalViewModel _salesTerminalViewModel;
        public ICommand PrintCommand { get; set; }
        public PosDefaultWindow(SalesTerminalViewModel salesTerminalViewModel)
        {
            //Set the data context
            _salesTerminalViewModel = salesTerminalViewModel;
            this.DataContext = _salesTerminalViewModel;
    
    
            PrintCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecutePrintCommand);
            this.Closing += PosCustomPrintWindow_Closing;
            this.Loaded += PosCustomPrintWindow_Loaded;
        }
        private void PosCustomPrintWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TemplateHelper.SrNo = 0;
            //ActiveTemplateParse();
    
            InitializeComponent();
            // Automatically call PrintButton_Click to start printing when the window opens
            if (PrintSlip(PrintArea).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        private void ActiveTemplateParse()
        {
            _salesTerminalViewModel.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            _salesTerminalViewModel.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt");
        }
    
        private void PosCustomPrintWindow_Closing(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure that the focus is correctly set when closing
            if (this.Owner != null)
            {
                this.Owner.Focus();
    
            }
        }
        public async Task<bool> PrintSlip(UIElement printArea)
        {
            // Ensure the content is fully rendered
            printArea.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(printArea.RenderSize.Width, printArea.RenderSize.Height));
            printArea.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Size(printArea.RenderSize.Width, printArea.RenderSize.Height)));
    
            // Create a PrintDialog
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    
            // Show the print dialog to the user
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                // Print only the specified visual (PrintArea)
                printDialog.PrintVisual(printArea, "POS Slip Print");
            }
    
            return true;
        }
    
        private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Pass the PrintArea to the PrintSlip method
            if (PrintSlip(PrintArea).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        private void ExecutePrintCommand(object parameter)
        {
    
            // Call the same PrintButton_Click logic here
            PrintButton_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }

}


You've "fixed" the "Header Row" at Height = 30. The StackPanel Margin of 10 is supposed to account for what? And perhaps the "Page Margins" need to be accounted for (more) ?

Header Row's Height and Stack Panel's Margin is add just to make the slip look more appealing. I'd made changes to them as per you suggested but it was of no help. What i think is that issue is not in .xaml file but its .cs from where I'm calling the print.

The "problem" is your 2 "visuals" don't match. The print is supposed to be off the "visual". The visual doesn;t have to be "visualized"; it can be off screen. So, your mismatched images are absolutely no help. You need to prototype where you can see the entire visual; not how it looks on a particular device (chopped off). Or use a ViewBox.
